# Remove-Physical Disk don't progress on my Windows 2016 cluster

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

I have 2 Windows2016 servers in a  cluster shared volume

One of my 18 (2*9) hard disk reports a failure so I want to remove from my S2D pool

This disk is marked as "retired"

```
$disk=Get-PhysicalDisk -SerialNumber 8HG42ZHH

PS C:\Windows\system32> $disk
FriendlyName         SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus                        HealthStatus Usage       Size
------------         ------------ ------- -----------------                        ------------ -----       ----
HGST HUH721212AL5200 8HG42ZHH     False   {Removing From Pool, Lost Communication} Warning      Retired 10.69 TB
```

so I must remove this disk from the pool with

```
Get-StoragePool *S2D* | Remove-PhysicalDisk –PhysicalDisk $disk
```

But this job hangs and never progress even after 12 hours of hard work as shown here

```
Get-StorageJob

Name               IsBackgroundTask ElapsedTime JobState  PercentComplete BytesProcessed BytesTotal
----               ---------------- ----------- --------  --------------- -------------- ----------
RemovePhysicalDisk False            00:00:00    Running   0
Repair             False            00:00:00    Starting  0
Repair             True             00:30:48    Suspended 0               0              805306368
```

The job stays in Running mode and doesn't progress, even when I try with multiple reboots.

Can you explain why I cannot remove this disk?

Please I need your help for this sad problem, if you have any question , please don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks for your time and your help

Answer (score 2):

WS2016 individual S2D disk evacuation process is broken, you need to a) backup your data, b) devastate S2D cluster/pool/etc, c) create it fresh new from the scratch, and d) get your data back from the backup.